# Rubymine HAML autocompletion similar to SublimeText 3

Tags: ruby, haml, sublimetext, rubymine

I have a SublimeText 3 and RubyMine 2016.1 versions installed. When I work with HAML files in Sublime, I have a nice auto-completion similar to this:

As I type `h1` and press `Tab` it becomes `%h1`, so I don't have to type `%` symbol.

Tried the same thing in RubyMine and nothing happened.

How can I achieve same auto-completion feature in RubyMine HAML as I had in a Sublime? Is that even possible or should I consider this behaviour as a feature of RubyMine IDE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this kind of auto completion is supported in Rubymine.

By the way, even the code completion in HTML templates requires you to first type the `<` character so that auto-completion starts presenting suggestions, so I guess it is a general intention of the Jetbrains team to require the user to type the special character (such as `%` in HAML) first.

For a while I thought you might be able to add this functionality using [Textmate Bundles import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/tutorial-using-textmate-bundles.html) (Textmate bundles use the same format as Sublime bundles), but it appears that only the syntax-highlighting rules in them are supported in Rubymine. So this approach probably won't work either even if you managed to find a bundle with the auto completion feature for HAML files.

Comment: Thanks for putting your time in! I will take a look at Textmate thing, maybe there is a open window left in Jetbrains Team busy schedule to consider this feature. I will open a suggestion on their tracker.